# How do I deploy a Sunderer?

Tags: planetside-2

I've been playing some planetside lately and I can't figure out how to deploy a Sunderer and let my allys spawn.

How do I do that? I tried pretty much every key on my keyboard, and they dont seem to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the <kbd>B</kbd> key. However, before you can deploy a Sunderer you have to unlock the certification to do so. The one you need is the [Sunderer Advanced Mobile Station (S-AMS)](http://wiki.planetside-universe.com/ps/Sunderer_Advanced_Mobile_Station_%28S-AMS%29), which costs 50 cert points.

Don't forget to also equip the upgrade on the vehicle customization screen after unlocking it. You can only deploy when the Sunderer is stationary, on reasonably flat terrain. You can't deploy if there is already another Sunderer deployed nearby (the limit is on the order of 50 metres and shows up on the minimap).

Comment: Don't forget to also equip the upgrade on the vehicle customization screen after unlocking it.

Comment: Edit suggestion was rejected but the above is now outdated and inaccurate: S-AMS is now baseline - it no longer needs to be unlocked and it is always equipped (does not occupy a slot).